# Connecting to ftp via Java Wrapper gives Error

Tags: java, ftp

Through Command

i open `ftp` command like :

```
"C:\Users\`akuma142`>ftp  19.236.236.61
Connected to 19.236.236.61.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
User (19.236.236.61:(none)): akuma142
331 Password required for akuma142.
Password:
```

Same thing i want to try with java wrapper class but getting error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOExc enter code here`eption: Cannot run program "c:\Users\akuma142\ftp   19.236.236.61": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>       at java.lang.Proc

```
p public void execute() throws IOException  
        {  

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\Users\\akuma142\\\\ftp   19.236.236.61"," \\10.22.22.33. -u akuma142 -p Ashuasasas ping 10.40.34.56 ");
            Process p = pb.start();"
```

Comment: Did you just expose your password to us? If so better change that immediately. And spend more time to properly format your question too

Comment: This password is not correct i have just given it manually

Comment: Summarized question title and added tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this way:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe", "D:\\MyDocument\\argument.txt");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad D:\\MyDocument\\argument.txt");
```

Comment: ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\akuma142\\ftp 19.236.236.61"," -u akuma142 -p Ashuasasas");
             Process p = pb.start();

Comment: ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\akuma142\\ftp.exe", "19.236.236.61", "-u akuma142 -p Ashuasasas");
Process p = pb.start();